# PrestaShop cloned for two countries ¿good practice?

Tags: git, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a shop in PrestaShop and I want to sell in another country with a different domain. In my hosting I can't use the multishop with different domains so I have cloned the shop and upload to the hosting of the other country.

My question is because I am using git and I am doing serious modifications in the code so I have created another remote for the new country. ¿Is this a good practice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the worry of mutlishop is specific to Prestashop and not the host, so you can activate it (which I think would be best).

Regards,

Comment: Yes I can activate it but in my hosting I can't point more than obe domain to my website dir. Si is impossible for me to have multishop in different domains.